# Deleted the app code which is used by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I had a small break of my app project, during this "free time" I accentily deleted the app code. I had it stored in my downloads folder which from time and time I clean up, in a rough fashion.

Now I still have the app on my mobile and managed to get the app file named: "com.example.username.projectname" from my mobile to my laptop. I only used my phone as a emulator and can run the code fine on my mobile. Now is there any way of recovery for my project so I can start to work on my project again. Or is the only option to start all over again?

Comment: "Now I still have the app on my mobile" if you mean by that the compiled app, then without reverse engineering, you can't.

Comment: You see I don't know if its a compiled app. As the file that I got isn't a APK file, it was in a temp folder. And this file is also overwritten by Android Studio when a new version of the app is applied.

Comment: check local history in android studio and use tools to recover the deleted file

Comment: And next time use version control!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to rebuilt my app from scratch. The difficulties to reverse engineer the APK file were to many. Trying to restore the file via deleted file restores software didn't resolve the problem either. Because of this experience I backup my app every time when I make a change to it.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you had the app in the mobile. Take a backup of the apk and try decompiling the apk using available apk decompiling tools